# Convert .NET locale to jQuery locale - when a national variety (eg. "-US" or "-MX") is not present in local resources

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, locale, globalization

I noticed `jQuery` has one locale for `Spanish` which is `es`.  When you change your browser to a `spanish locale` which can be `es, es-US, es-MX, etc`, since there is only one jQuery spanish file, it only loads the file if the locale is `es`.  Is there a way to convert between the locales that .NET returns to you using the `CultureInfo` object to the ones that jQuery expects?

Here is scenario to better explain my situation.  If I change my browsers language to `es`, `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` returns `es-ES`, however, jQuery does not contain the locale `es-ES`, it just has `es`, but in certain cases it does have something like `en-US` and `en-GB`, so what is the best way to go about this. Should I just rename locale files or do some sort of conversion?

Comment: Doesn't jQuery automatically load the `es` locale if the `es-US` is requested but not present?

Comment: @Dirk - I tried this and it does not appear to be doing it.  I set my browser language to `es` and `CurrentCulture` returned `es-ES`, so the only way I got it to work was to have an `es-ES` jquery script.

Answer (score 0):

Living in Belgium we have similar problems for french, dutch, english and combinations of these cultures.

For my datepicker setup I came up with the idea of using the `html` tag as culture placeholder, feeded from `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` or something server side.

```
<html lang="nl-BE" />
```

Then in JavaScript I first detect the current culture and see if it's valid according to a list and a default culture. I therefor split the language, and see if the language is available in my available cultures. If not I use the default one.

```
// var cfg.options -> $.extend to this.settings
options: {
    ...
    defaultCulture: 'en-GB',
    validCultures: ['en-GB', 'fr', 'fr-BE', 'nl-BE', 'nl'],
    ...
},

getCulture: function () {
    var settings = this.settings,
        cache = settings.cache,
        dynamicProp = settings.dynamicProp,
        options = settings.options,
        culture = $(cache.currentCulture).prop(dynamicProp.culture), // $('html').prop('lang')
        language;

    if ($.inArray(culture, options.validCultures) === -1) {
        language = culture.split('-')[0];
        culture = $.inArray(language, options.validCultures) === -1 ? options.defaultCulture : language;
    }

    return culture;
},
```

After my wicked implementation skills the customer asked to change the dates for `fr-BE` and I ended up creating a custom culture file in jQuery UI :s
That was the easiest solution.

I believe it all depends on how custom your cultures have to be setup. If the data/translations provided by jQuery UI is enough to meet requirements, I wouldn't create custom cultures.